# What are the differences between keychain and ssh-ident

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, keychain

I'm considering using a tool to setup my `ssh-agent` environment so I only need to enter my `ssh` key once.

What is the difference between [`ssh-ident`](https://github.com/ccontavalli/ssh-ident) and [`keychain`](https://github.com/funtoo/keychain)? Does one have advantages over the other?

Comment: I have never heard of your `keychain` or `ssh-ident`. Why not to use standard `gnome-keyring` (preinstalled and configured in Ubuntu) or directly `ssh-agent`? They do everything you require from them (*"I only need to enter my ssh key once."*).

Comment: `ssh-agent` only applies to sub-processes. The two mentioned programs `allow you to easily have one long running ssh-agent process per system, rather than the norm of one ssh-agent per login session.` (From [here](https://github.com/funtoo/keychain)). Would `gnome-keyring` solve this issue?

Comment: If you run it outside of your session, it will work the same way, as late as you retain the connection to this agent (env. variable SSH_AUTH_SOCK).

Comment: The management (eg securly setting) of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` is the raison d'être of the two tools I mention.

Comment: I would be very interested how you do security and management of environment variable.

Comment: [This](http://rabexc.org/posts/pitfalls-of-ssh-agents) explains why it's not as simple as `[ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" ] && eval \`ssh-agent -s\` &&  ssh-add `. The two listed tools address these issues.

Comment: It is not particularly true. The first bash you start is the one where you start you x session and the environment variables are inherited to all the others.

Comment: What you say doesn't hold if you are not using `X`, but it is true generally true for most users.

Answer (score 7):

Please look at this answer over on the Unix Stack Exchange site:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90869

---

### *ssh-key* with passphrase, with *ssh-ident*

*ssh-ident* is an utility that can manage *ssh-agent* on your behalf and load identities as necessary. It adds keys only once as they are needed, regardless of how many terminals, SSH or login sessions that require access to an SSH agent.

### *ssh-key* with passphrase, with *keychain*

*keychain* is a small utility which manages *ssh-agent* on your behalf and allows the SSH agent to remain running when the login session ends. On subsequent logins, *keychain* will connect to the existing SSH agent instance.

Comment: I figured since I'm posting a link to another StackExchange site that the linked page rule wouldn't apply... apparently each sub-site has their own interpretation of this policy.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. And no, this isn't a site-dependent thing. No site on the SE network accepts a link as an answer, not even a link to another SE site.