# keychain vs ssh-ident for WSL2

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ssh-agent, passphrase, keychain

I tried to avoid retyping ssh passphrase for git. Turns out there's no one way to it.

Not sure why [keychain vs ssh-ident](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857935/keychain-vs-ssh-ident) counts as opinion-based.

Also, that question was asked for a full linux system where distribution-specific things like `gnome-keyring` was suggested. I am looking for a generic solution for WSL2.

keychain and ssh-ident seems like 2 options that strike balance between security and convenience(based on https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90869/306145).

Comment: Software recommendation questions do tend to be more subjective than other types.  While "pure" software recommendation questions are typically allowed here (as long as they relate to Ubuntu), some questions tend to veer too much into "opinion".  What's an advantage in one particular use-case may be a disadvantage in another, and "striking a balance" even has to be done in light of individual use-cases.  I'm assuming that's why the linked question was closed.  See [How to ask and answer Software Recommendation Questions](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1872/1165986) for more info.  Thanks!

Comment: With that in mind, it's a bit unclear exactly what you are asking here.  Can you edit to make it more clear?  Thanks!